# Vector of pointers undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a vector of pointers whose elements are pointing to vector of int elements. (I'm solving a competitive programming-like problem, that's why it sounds kinda nonsense).

but here's the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int ct = 0;

vector<int> vec;

vector<int*> rf;

void addRef(int n){
    vec.push_back(n);
    rf.push_back(&vec[ct]);
    ct++;
}


int main(){
    addRef(1);
    addRef(2);
    addRef(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < ct; i++){
        cout << *rf[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < ct; i++){
        cout << vec[i] << ' ';  
    }
}
```

When I execute the code, it's showing weird behaviour that I don't understand. The first element of rf (`vector<int*>`) seems not pointing to the vec's (`vector<int>`) element, where the rest of the elements are pointing to it.

here's the output when I run it on Dev-C++:

```
1579600 2 5
1 2 5
```

When I tried to run the code [here](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/), the output is even weirder:

```
1197743856 0 5 
1 2 5
```

The code is intended to have same output between the first line and the second.

Can you guys explain why it happens? Is there any mistake in my implementation?

thanks

Comment: Take note of the [vector::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) documentation. In part, observe that if the vector has to increase its capacity, all references to existing elements are invalidated. That means that calling `vec.push_back(n)` can invalidate pointers that you added to `rf` previously. You may want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 3):

Adding elements to a `std::vector` with `push_back` or similar may invalidate all iterators and references to its elements.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back.

The idea is that in order to grow the vector, it may not have enough free memory to expand into, and thus may have to move the whole array to some other location in memory, freeing the old block.  That means in particular that your pointers now point to memory that has been freed, or reused for something else.

If you want to keep this approach, you will need to `resize()` or `reserve()` a sufficient number of elements in `vec` before starting.  Which of course defeats the whole purpose of a `std::vector`, and you might as well use an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

The vector is changing sizes and the addresses you are saving might not be those you want. You can preallocate memory using `reserve()` and the vector will not resize.

```
  vec.reserve(3);
  addRef(1);
  addRef(2);
  addRef(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs when you call vec.push_back(n) and vec’s internal array is already full.  When that happens, the std::vector::push_back() method allocates a larger array, copies the contents of the full array over to the new array, then frees the old/full array and keeps the new one.

Usually that’s all you need, but your program is keeping pointers to elements of the old array inside (rf), and these pointers all become dangling/invalid when the reallocation occurs, hence the funny (undefined) behavior.

An easy fix would be to call vec.reserve(100) (or similar) at the top of your program (so that no further reallocations are necessary).  Or alternatively you could postpone the adding of pointers to (rf) until after you’ve finished adding all the values to (vec).

Answer (score 3):

Just do not take pointer from a `vector` that may change soon. `vector` will copy the elements to a new space when it enlarges its capacity.

Use an array to store the `int`s instead.